# Custom Icons for TwentySeconds CV Side Bar

Tags: cv

Instead of `website` I want a custom `icon` for `GitHub` and an additional `icon` for `Youtube Channel` this my `twenty-minutes-CV syle

```
\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% PROFILE SIDE BAR %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% personal info
%\profilepic{capure mi.PNG}          % path of profile pic
\cvname{James Daniel}                   % your name
\cvjobtitle{Daniel}          % your actual job position
\cvdate{07 July 1980}        % date of birth
\cvaddress{Nigeria}       % address
\cvnumberphone{+234 08033147591}   % telephone number
\cvmail{eautocorrelation@yahoo.com}    % e-mail
\cvsite{http://github.com/sta189332} % personal site
%\cvsites{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2U6PP34CggzYB_49H-Nd-g}
\faIcon{github}
\faIcon{youtube}

\aboutme{

\noindent James is an R developer with a degree in Statistics, proficient in Data Science. Passionate about technology and transmitting knowledge to all audiences.Perceptive and logical programmer with proven ability to communicate technical, professionals and end-users to identify and translate business requirements.
} % About me section

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float) %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\skills{{R Programming Language/5.2},{Python Programming Language/4},{\LaTeX/5.5},{CSPro/4.7}, 
{Data Science/4.8}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\skillstext{{lovely/4},{narcissistic/3}}

\makeprofile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% END PROFILE SIDE BAR %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% BODY %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Simple Section
%\section{interests}
%The heroine and the dreamer of Wonderland;  James is the principal character.

\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% TWENTY LIST ITEMS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%    Four arguments: date; title; where; description %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem
    {From 2019}
    {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Statistics}}
    {Fed. University of Tech., Akure}
    {\emph{Specializing in Time Series Modeling.}}
  \twentyitem
    {2015-2018}
    {M.Sc. Statistics}
    {University of Ilorin, Ilorin}
    {Specializing in General Statistics.}
  \twentyitem
    {2013-2014}
    {PGD Statistics}
    {NNamdi Azikwe University, Awka}
    {Specializing in General Statistics.}
  \twentyitem
    {2004-2008}
    {HND Statistics}
    {Inst. of Manag. and Tech., Enugu}
    {Specializing in General Statistics.}
\end{twenty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%TWENTY LIST SHORTITEMS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Two arguments: date; title/description %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Publications}
\begin{twentyshort}
  \twentyitemshort
    {2016}
    {\href{https://www.ijsciences.com/pub/article/922}{Time Series Analysis of All Shares Index of Nigerian Stock Exchange: A Box-Jenkins Approach, }International Journal Sciences - Volume 5}
  \twentyitemshort
    {2017}
    {\href{http://www.akamaiuniversity.us/PJST18_2_88.pdf}{A Bootstrap Method for Box-Jenkins Models with Application on Brent Crude Oil Prices per Barrel, }The Pacific Journal of Science and Technology, Volume 18}
  \twentyitemshort
    {2019}
    {\href{http://anale-informatica.tibiscus.ro/download/lucrari/17-1-11-Daniel.pdf}{Time Series Analysis of Brent Crude Oil Prices Per Barrel: A Box-Jenkins Approach, }Annals of Computer Science Series. 17th Tome 1st Fasc.}

\end{twentyshort}

\section{Awards}
\begin{twentyshort}
  \twentyitemshort
    {2008}
    {Best Graduating Student of the Department. Dept of Statistics, IMT, Enugu}
\end{twentyshort}

\section{Experience}
\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem
    {2012 till date}
    {James in National Bureau of Statistics.}
    {Statistician}
    {}
  \twentyitem
    {2010 - 2012}
    {Industrial and General Insurance Plc, Nigeria.}
    {Risk Management Officer}
    {}
\twentyitem
    {2009 - 2010}
    {Bank of Agriculture, Nigeria.}
    {Data Entry Officer}
    {}

\end{twenty}
\section{MEMBERSHIP OF PROFESSIONAL BODIES}
The Nigerian Statistical Association
\section{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}
Nigerian Red Cross Society

\section{Referees}
\textbf{Kayode Ayinde, Professor, Fed. University of Tech., Akure}\\ 08035850519 - 
\href{mailto:kayinde@futa.edu.ng}{kayinde@futa.edu.ng}

\textbf{Adebowale O. Adejumo, Professor, University of Ilorin, Ilorin}\\ 08020383709 - 
\href{mailto:aodejumo@unilorin.edu.ng}{aodejumo@unilorin.edu.ng}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% ENDBODY %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image: My Twenty Seconds CV]

I have found `\faIcon{github}` with `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` in the preamble but I do not know how to use it. When I use it as it is in my code, it does bring work but the `icons` are placed in the body of the cv instead of the sidebar. I have shown where I do not want the `icons` to show up with the red pen colour and indicate where I want it to show up with the blue pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}
    
%%%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\newcommand{\givenyoutube}{}
\newcommand{\cvyoutube}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenyoutube}{#1}} 
\renewcommand{\makeprofile}
{
    % grey bar on the left side
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)
        \begin{flushleft}
            \hspace{13pt}
            
            % profile picture
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\givenprofilepic}{}}{}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
                    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
                    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\givenprofilepic}};
            \end{tikzpicture}}
            
            % name
            {\Huge\color{mainblue}\givencvname}
            
            % jobtitle
            \begin{flushright}
                {\Large\color{black!80}\givencvjobtitle}
            \end{flushright}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
            
            % table with icons 
            \begin{tabular}{c @{\hskip 0.2cm} p{5cm}}
                % CV date
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
                % CV address
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
                % CV phone
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \givennumberphone\\}
                % CV site
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faIcon{github}}} & \href{\givencvsite}{\givencvsite}\\}
                % CV mail
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail}{\givencvmail}\\[3pt]}
                % CV youtube
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\givenyoutube}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faIcon{youtube}}} & \url{\givenyoutube}}
                
            \end{tabular}
            
            % about me text
            \profilesection{About me}{3.2cm}
            \givenaboutme
            
            % skills with scale
            \profilesection{Skill}{5cm}
            \givenskill
            \giventextskill
            \noindent
            \scriptsize
            \noindent
            (*)[The skill scale is from 0 (Fundamental Awareness) to 6 (Expert).]
            
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{textblock}
    \vspace{-10pt}
}   
%%%********************************************

\begin{document}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% PROFILE SIDE BAR %%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % personal info
    %\profilepic{capure mi.PNG}          % path of profile pic
    \cvname{James Daniel}                   % your name
    \cvjobtitle{Daniel}          % your actual job position
    \cvdate{07 July 1980}        % date of birth
    \cvaddress{Nigeria}       % address
    \cvnumberphone{+234 08033147591}   % telephone number
    \cvmail{eautocorrelation@yahoo.com}    % e-mail
    \cvsite{http://github.com/sta189332} % personal site
    \cvyoutube{https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2U6PP34CggzYB\_49H-Nd-g} % added <<<<<< <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \aboutme{           
        \noindent James is an R developer with a degree in Statistics, proficient in Data Science. Passionate about technology and transmitting knowledge to all audiences. Perceptive and logical programmer with proven ability to communicate technical, professionals and end-users to identify and translate business requirements.
    } % About me section
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float) %%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \skills{{R Programming Language/5.2},{Python Programming Language/4},{\LaTeX/5.5},{CSPro/4.7}, 
        {Data Science/4.8}}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \skillstext{{lovely/4},{narcissistic/3}}
    
    \makeprofile
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% END PROFILE SIDE BAR %%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%% BODY %%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Simple Section
    %\section{interests}
    %The heroine and the dreamer of Wonderland;  James is the principal character.
    
    \section{Education}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% TWENTY LIST ITEMS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%    Four arguments: date; title; where; description %%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{twenty}
        \twentyitem
        {From 2019}
        {Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Statistics}}
        {Fed. University of Tech., Akure}
        {\emph{Specializing in Time Series Modeling.}}
        \twentyitem
        {2015-2018}
        {M.Sc. Statistics}
        {University of Ilorin, Ilorin}
        {Specializing in General Statistics.}
        \twentyitem
        {2013-2014}
        {PGD Statistics}
        {NNamdi Azikwe University, Awka}
        {Specializing in General Statistics.}
        \twentyitem
        {2004-2008}
        {HND Statistics}
        {Inst. of Manag. and Tech., Enugu}
        {Specializing in General Statistics.}
    \end{twenty}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%TWENTY LIST SHORTITEMS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% Two arguments: date; title/description %%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Publications}
    \begin{twentyshort}
        \twentyitemshort
        {2016}
        {\href{https://www.ijsciences.com/pub/article/922}{Time Series Analysis of All Shares Index of Nigerian Stock Exchange: A Box-Jenkins Approach, }International Journal Sciences - Volume 5}
        \twentyitemshort
        {2017}
        {\href{http://www.akamaiuniversity.us/PJST18_2_88.pdf}{A Bootstrap Method for Box-Jenkins Models with Application on Brent Crude Oil Prices per Barrel, }The Pacific Journal of Science and Technology, Volume 18}
        \twentyitemshort
        {2019}
        {\href{http://anale-informatica.tibiscus.ro/download/lucrari/17-1-11-Daniel.pdf}{Time Series Analysis of Brent Crude Oil Prices Per Barrel: A Box-Jenkins Approach, }Annals of Computer Science Series. 17th Tome 1st Fasc.}
        
    \end{twentyshort}
    
    \section{Awards}
    \begin{twentyshort}
        \twentyitemshort
        {2008}
        {Best Graduating Student of the Department. Dept of Statistics, IMT, Enugu}
    \end{twentyshort}
    
    \section{Experience}
    \begin{twenty}
        \twentyitem
        {2012 till date}
        {James in National Bureau of Statistics.}
        {Statistician}
        {}
        \twentyitem
        {2010 - 2012}
        {Industrial and General Insurance Plc, Nigeria.}
        {Risk Management Officer}
        {}
        \twentyitem
        {2009 - 2010}
        {Bank of Agriculture, Nigeria.}
        {Data Entry Officer}
        {}
        
    \end{twenty}
    \section{MEMBERSHIP OF PROFESSIONAL BODIES}
    The Nigerian Statistical Association
    \section{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}
    Nigerian Red Cross Society
    
    \section{Referees}
    \textbf{Kayode Ayinde, Professor, Fed. University of Tech., Akure}\\ 08035850519 - 
    \href{mailto:kayinde@futa.edu.ng}{kayinde@futa.edu.ng}
    
    \textbf{Adebowale O. Adejumo, Professor, University of Ilorin, Ilorin}\\ 08020383709 - 
    \href{mailto:aodejumo@unilorin.edu.ng}{aodejumo@unilorin.edu.ng}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%% ENDBODY %%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```